# Remove everything from trailing forward slash

Tags: ruby, string

Starting with this string:

```
file = "[/my/directory/file-*.log]"
```

I want to remove anything that comes after the trailing `/` and the closing square bracket, so the returned string is:

```
file = "[/my/directory/]"
```

I wondered if someone could recommend the safest way to do this.

I have been experimenting with `chomp` but I’m not getting anywhere, and `gsub` or `sub` doesn’t seem to fit either.

Comment: Do you really need the filename to be inside square brackets?

Comment: That part is out of my control I’m afraid ☹️

Comment: Crispy, the characters preceding the left bracket and following the right bracket are not double quotes (two places). Please edit.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about removing anything that comes after the closing square bracket. Isn't that part trivial, and misleading/confusing, given that that part is already to be deleted, being after the trailing slash?

Comment: Actually, it is not clear what you are asking. You wrote you want to remove anything that comes after the trailing slash, but in your expected string, you have a closing bracket, which comes after the slash.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `File.dirname`:

```
File.dirname("/my/directory/file-*.log")
=> "/my/directory"
```

Comment: and this is fasters way btw. Even if wrap with brackets. [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/howtwizer/66e9272f8ac603623e47f9850839478d)

Comment: Where have the brackets gone? @OleksiiBaidan: `"[#{File.dirname(file)}/]" #=> "[[/my/directory/]"`. Do you mean, `"#{File.dirname(file)}/]"`? What is the purpose of the preceding line at your benchmark, `File.dirname(path)`? btw, it's not "even if wrap with brackets"; it's clear that the brackets are there.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three non-regex solutions:

```
file[0..file.rindex('/')] << ']'

file.sub(file[file.rindex('/')+1..-2], '')

"[#{File.dirname(file[1..-2])}]"
```

All return `"[/my/directory/]"`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's stuck inside the brackets, you can always write a custom replacement function that calls out to `File.dirname`:

```
def squaredir(file)
  file.sub(/\[([^]]+)\]/) do |m|
    '[%s]' % File.dirname($1)
  end
end
```

Then you get this:

```
squaredir("[/my/directory/file-*.log]")
# => "[/my/directory]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file.split('/').take(file.split('/').size - 1).join('/') + ']'
=> "[/my/directory]"
```

1. Split the string into an array of strings separated by `/`
2. Take all the array elements except the last element
3. Join the strings together, re-inserting `/` between them
4. Add a trailing `]`

Answer (score -1):

```
file = "[/my/directory/file-*.log]"
file.sub(/^(.+)\/([^\/]+)\]/, '\1/]')
=> "[/my/directory/]"
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote so I can address the issue.